# How to save Capture image from camera in IPhone device Photo Library?

Tags: iphone

I m working on one of the project in which I have to save the captured image in IPhone Device Photo library.

What I want to ask how to implement this through code.Here below I m pasting my codes :--

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
imgglobal =imageView.image;
NSString *newFilePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"~/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/SAVE_IMAGE_TEST1.JPG"]; 
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
NSData  *data = imageData;
if (imageData != nil) {
    [imageData writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
}
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"~/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/SAVE_IMAGE_TEST1.JPG" contents:data attributes:nil])
{
    UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Image was successfully saved to the Photo Library." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [successAlert show];
    [successAlert release];
} else {
    UIAlertView     *failureAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure" message:@"Failed to save image to the Photo Library." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [failureAlert show];
    [failureAlert release];
}
```

}

But  my application show failure alert please send me the right code to save the captured image into the Iphone device Photo library.

Thanks in Advance its very urgent

Comment: @AmanGupta007I am facing the same problem,  please give me some suggestion how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's a one-liner (not counting error processing). Just call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`.

Comment: BegemannHi I am facing the same problem, i need to save capture photo from camera to the iphone device gallery. so user can copy directly from his device. please give me some suggestion how it is possible?thanks